# Python Chromedriver opens command prompt with browser

Tags: python, google-chrome, selenium, webdriver, command-prompt

I am on Windows and trying to run a pretty simple code:

```
from selenium import webdriver

chromedriver = '/path/to/chromedriver'
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chromedriver)
driver.get('https://www.google.com')
```

For some reason when I run this code I will get the browser to open but the command prompt will open as well.  Did I do something wrong or is this supposed to happen?  How can I get it to only open the browser and not command prompt?

Comment: When you say you run this code, do you mean you are running it through command line with the python command like this `python my_file.py` or do you mean when you double click on the .py file?

Comment: @Michael Platt Sorry, I have the code in a .py file and I run the file by clicking "Run" on the tool bar followed by "Run Module".  I did see something that said to save it as a .pyw file to open it as a .exe but it still opens the command prompt.

Comment: I believe it's the case that if you run the code like that you'll always have a popup showing because that's how it's supposed to work right?  Output needs to be redirected somewhere, in this case, to a command prompt that will open.  However, if you run it through command line using the python command it shouldn't open the extra window.

Answer (score 1):

It's nothing abnormal,It's just how selenium works.You can hide command prompt by

```
driverService.HideCommandPromptWindow = true;
```

The above code hides the command prompt